incidence coefficients in homological integration theory
I originally asked this on MSE but received no answers so I'm asking here.
I haven't found any reference on this after lots of looking since I first asked that question in February, so I think that qualifies it as research-level math.
In the theory of CW complexes, the incidence coefficient between a cell $\sigma$ of dimension $k$ and a cell $\tau$ of dimension $k - 1$ of a complex is defined as the topological degree of the map $\phi$ that attaches $\tau$ into $\sigma$, or 0 if $\tau$ is not contained in $\sigma$.
If we write the incidence number as $[\sigma, \tau]$, we can then define the boundary operator as
$$\partial\sigma = \sum_\tau [\sigma, \tau]\tau$$
where the sum is over all $k - 1$-dimensional cells of the complex.
By contrast, in geometric or homological integration theory, the chain modules are spaces of currents.
We define boundary operators by how they act on differential forms:
$$\langle \partial \sigma, u\rangle = \langle \sigma, du\rangle$$
where $u$ is a $k$-form, by analogy with Stokes' theorem.
Can we define an analogous notion of incidence number for currents?
I'm fine with an answer that requires restriction to e.g. currents of finite mass with finite boundary mass.
I suspect that this is possible with some kind of Riesz representation trick but I haven't seen it written out anywhere.
I feel like you could do it by thinking of some appropriate subspace of currents as elements of the duals of Sobolev spaces of differential forms and then use the Hilbert space structure.

I emailed the author of this book and he suggested an answer.
Let $\|\cdot\|$ be the mass norm on currents.
For a pair of currents $\sigma$, $\tau$, define
$$[\sigma, \tau] = \text{sign}\left\{\|\partial\sigma + \tau\| - \|\partial\sigma - \tau\|\right\}.$$
It seems to give the same answer as the usual formula for simplices and cubes.
If $\tau$ and $\partial\sigma$ intersect along a surface of lower dimension that that of $\tau$, it gives zero as desired.
